# Est-ce que « Je n’ai jamais + …+ de ma vie » est un pléonasme?

Tags: expressions, choix-de-mot, expressions-idiomatiques, formulation-idiomatique

Exemple:

Je n’ai jamais mangé un aussi bon burger au poulet de toute ma vie (au sens de « c’est le meilleur burger que j’ai eu l’occasion de manger depuis mon existence).

Selon plusieurs dictionnaires que j’ai consultés, ces deux termes seraient synonymes, alors les employer ensemble rendrait-il une phrase pléonastique ?

Serait-il préférable de juste écrire:

Je n’ai mangé de toute ma vie un aussi bon burger au poulet.

Voire de repenser la phrase entièrement?

Comment: Avec les superlatifs le subjonctif est souvent utile, *c'est le meilleur burger que j'aie jamais eu.*

Comment: @livresque "Avoir un burger" sort tout droit de "to have a burger", c'est à dire que c'est un anglicisme, qui n'est pas utilisé en français, tout au moins pas encore, je pense. En disant « … que j'aie jamais eu dans mon réfrigérateur » ça serait correct.

Comment: L'expression correcte n'est pas « depuis mon existence », mais «_de toute mon existence »  (https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=depuis+mon+existence%2Cde+toute+mon+existence&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=fr-2019&smoothing=3-existence « période pendant laquelle quelque chose ou quelqu'un existe » (le reste de mon existence)
-https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/existence) à moins qu'il  s'agisse d'un canadianisme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Il est vrai que l'on trouve la combinaison « [n'ai jamais de ma vie](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22n%27ai%20jamais%20de%20ma%20vie%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr) » quelques fois ; parmi celles-ci, « de ma vie » est parfois écrit après une virgule, et donc on peut considérer que ce n'est pas tout à fait un emploi pléonastique, cet usage étant celui d'un adverbe emphatique, un peu comme lorsqu'on dit « jamais, au grand jamis » (presque toujours avec une virgule, [des dizaines et des dizaines d'exemples](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22jamais%20au%20grand%20jamais%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr)).

On trouve encore près de vingt occurrences de « [jamais … de toute ma vie](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22de%20toute%20ma%20vie%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr) ».

Il n'y a pas de doute que toutes ces constructions ont quelque chose de plus ou moins pléonastique. On peut choisir de les éviter, en particulier celles qui ne comportent pas de virgule, cela en conscience d'une certitude que l'on pourra avoir que lorsqu'on dit « jamais », c'est bien « jamais », et pas autre chose, mais on oubliera peut-être que ce n'est pas la façon dont  tout le monde pense et que l'on ne peut pas toujours présumer de celle d'autrui, avec qui on doit quand même communiquer.

> Je n’ai mangé de toute ma vie un aussi bon burger au poulet.

Les formes négatives « [n'ai de ma vie](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22n%27ai%20de%20ma%20vie%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr) et « [n'ai de toute ma vie](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22n%27ai%20de%20toute%20ma%20vie%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr) », [n'a de sa vie](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22n%27a%20de%20sa%20vie%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr), sont utilisées. Selon le principe de la commutation, on ne peut rien reprocher à ces négations. Elles ne sont pas courantes, mais je ne saurais quoi dire de leur idiomaticité.

Pour ce qui est de la variante proposée, si on veut faire en sorte de l'aligner strictement selon le principe de commutation, elle devrait être modifiée comme suit.

- Je n’ai de toute ma vie mangé  un aussi bon burger au poulet.

*En français plus habituel*

- C'est le meilleur burger au poulet que j'ai jamais mangé.
- Il ne m'est pas arrivé une seule fois de manger un aussi bon burger au poulet.
- De tous les burgers au poulet que j'ai pu manger, c'est le meilleur.
- Dieu sait si j'en ai mangé des burgers au poulet, mais jamais un [aussi bon/bon comme celui-là].  (*lorsqu'on n'hésite pas à faire référence à Dieu dans le langage, et qu'on a mangé beaucoup de burgers au poulet*)

Answer (score 4):

***Jamais*** et ***de ma vie*** ne sont pas exactement synonymes. ***Jamais*** peut faire l'objet d'une restriction (ex: *Je n'ai jamais mangé de burgers au petit-déjeuner*) alors que ***de ma vie*** est absolu.

***De ma vie*** est de plus très rarement utilisé en remplacement de ***jamais*** (entre 250 et 800 fois moins d'après Google NGrams) et dans ce cas, les phrases sont de registre très soutenu :

> *Je n'ai de ma vie mangé un aussi bon burger.*

Exemples :

> *Nous avions oublié des verres : nous y suppléâmes par des chalumeaux de seigle, avec lesquels nous aspirions le vin dans la bouteille, nous piquant de choisir des tuyaux bien larges, pour pomper à qui mieux mieux. **Je n’ai de ma vie été si gai**.*
> Jean-Jacques Rousseau, *Les confessions*, 1782

> *Cher Louis, si jamais on vous parle du silence des ruines la nuit, exceptez, je vous prie, le burg sans nom de Neckarsteinach. **Je n'ai de ma vie entendu vacarme pareil**.*
> Victor Hugo, *Le Rhin, lettre à un ami*, 1812

> *Je n'ai, **de ma vie**, rien vu de plus horrible, de plus hideux, de plus dégoûtant.*
> Alexandre Dumas, *Le capitaine Rhino*, 1888

Answer (score 2):

> Je n’ai jamais mangé un aussi bon burger au poulet de toute ma vie.

Cette phrase est du français courant, convenable aussi bien dans un style oral familier que dans un style écrit soutenu. Il n'y a rien à redire sur la construction de la phrase. L'expression « de toute ma vie » renforce « jamais ».

Dans un style familier on peut bien sûr abréger la négation : « J'ai jamais mangé … ». Le mot « burger » n'est vraiment apparu en français qu'au 21<sup>e</sup> siècle et est encore souvent considéré comme un anglicisme : le terme établi est « hamburger ».

> <sup>?</sup>Je n’ai de toute ma vie mangé un aussi bon burger au poulet.
> <sup>?</sup>Je n’ai jamais de toute ma vie mangé un aussi bon burger au poulet.
> <sup>?</sup>Je n’ai mangé de toute ma vie un aussi bon burger au poulet.

Ces phrases sont grammaticalement correctes, mais le placement de « de toute ma vie » est très inhabituel en français moderne. C'est une langue très soutenue et vieillotte, dans laquelle le mot « burger » est déplacé.

Answer (score 1):

On pourrait dire ***Je n'ai jamais... depuis que je suis en France***, ou en utilisant une autre periode plus courte que ***toute ma vie***. Dans ce sens je suis d'accord avec la réponse par @jlliagre.

Néanmoins, il est tout à fait possible, que mon avis est basé sur l'interprétation trop littérale de l'expression ***de ma vie***.